# Draw a pendulum using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, canvas

Here is the code, I am drawing 2 circles and 2 lines and an additional line appears parallel to second line.[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtdsl.png)

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="Panel" height=500 width=500 style ="border: 1px dotted green">
        </canvas>
    </body>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("Panel");
            var draw = canvas.getContext("2d");
            draw.beginPath();
            draw.arc(canvas.width/2,100,10,2*Math.PI,false);
            draw.fillSytle="black"; 
            draw.fill();
            draw.arc(canvas.width/2,200,10,2*Math.PI,false);    
            draw.fillSytle="black"; 
            draw.fill();
            draw.moveTo(canvas.width/2,0);
            draw.lineTo(canvas.width/2,100);
            draw.moveTo(canvas.width/2,100);
            draw.lineTo(canvas.width/2,200);
            draw.stroke();
            </script>
    </head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the snippet below. You just need to draw two separate forms

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("Panel");
            var draw = canvas.getContext("2d");
            draw.beginPath();
            draw.arc(canvas.width/2 -50,200,10,2*Math.PI,false);   
            draw.fillSytle="black"; 
            draw.fill();
            draw.moveTo(canvas.width/2 -50,0);
            draw.lineTo(canvas.width/2 -50,200);
            draw.stroke();
            var draww = canvas.getContext("2d");
            draww.beginPath();    
            draww.arc(canvas.width/2 +50,200,10,2*Math.PI,false); 
            draww.fillSytle="black"; 
            draww.fill();   
            draww.moveTo(canvas.width/2 +50,0);
            draww.lineTo(canvas.width/2 +50,200);
            draww.stroke();
```

```html
 <canvas id="Panel" height=500 width=500 style ="border: 1px dotted green">
        </canvas>
```

Comment: No need for `draww = canvas.getContext("2d");` `getContext()` is going to return the same object as it did previously. All that is needed is to begin a new path

Comment: Will i have to do that for every Thing that i draw?
What is a better way to do graphics in javaScript?

Comment: You can always use a loop